# Does adding an index to a large data frame make lookups quicker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm new(ish) to pandas and am using using pandas dataframes in my code. The dataframes are quite large (containing upwards of 2M rows). I haven't added any indexes to the dataframe. One of the values in each row is the date associate with that row and what I am doing is processing data from the frame by date. I have a line of code that does the following:

```
these_trades = arc_trades[arc_trades['TradeDate'] == this_date]
```

So, I'm extracting only the values I need by date.

I have quite a strong database background and my question is **"Should I be adding an index to the DataFrame arc_trades to make the slicing faster"?** and, additionally, can I have multiple separate indexes for use in different slicing situations? If yes, how would I add the indexes?

Comment: Are your dates in a datetime format or are your dates strings? This will make a HUGE difference.

Comment: Its actually a string but I specifically formed the column TradeDate using arc_trades['TradeDate'] = arc_trades['TransactTime'].dt.to_period('D') so to make it a datetime64 would be easy. Is searching on datetimes faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does help to use an index in pandas. But coming from a database background you might overestimate the effect. In databases adding an index can speed things up 10x or even 100x. That is not the case in pandas.

If you time it, there is a significant effect using the index:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter

dates = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='D')
idx = np.random.choice(dates, 2000000)
df = pd.Series(1, index=idx).to_frame()

start = perf_counter()
these_trades = df[df.index == datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)]
perf_index = perf_counter() - start
print(f'With index: {perf_index}')

df = df.reset_index()

start = perf_counter()
these_trades = df[df['index'] == datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)]
perf_no_index = perf_counter() - start
print(f'Without index: {perf_no_index}')

df['index'] = df['index'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

start = perf_counter()
these_trades = df[df['index'] == '2020-01-01']
perf_as_string = perf_counter() - start
print(f'As string: {perf_as_string}')
```

Output:

```
With index: 0.007269900001119822
Without index: 0.01451519998954609
As string: 0.09630390000529587
```

So, it may be 30-50 % faster using an index vs. using a normal column. Good, but not great. Using datetimes is a magnitude (!) faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [set_index()](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-set_index.php#:%7E:text=The%20set_index()%20function%20is,index%20or%20expand%20on%20it.) in the date column and then do your research in this 'new' dataset, so it's supposed to be faster, but I think this kinda of optimization that you want should be done more formally with MySQL or similar Data Managament language or software.